# Ardour will not continue to record.

Tags: hard-drive, ram, ardour

I just recently bought a laptop. It has 5.2 GB of RAM and 624.2 GB on the hard drive. However, after only a few minutes of playing into my MIDI keyboard I get an error message saying that "This disk system on your computer was not able to keep up with Ardour. Specifically, it failed to write data to the disk quickly enough to keep up with the recording." Is there a way that I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! It was a latency problem. I had it set at 128 in the frames/period and port maximum settings in Qjackctl. After I changed this setting, it worked.